# Amplitude relation in wave propagation

Tags: waves, reflection, scattering

I have been taught that when a sound wave is traveling through a composite medium (denser first, rarer second)
Then the junction point act as a 'free end' and so there is both transmission and reflection.

One relation was given as
$$A_r + A_i = A_t$$
That is, sum of initial amplitude of wave and the amplitude of reflected wave is equal to the amplitude of transmitted wave (in rarer medium).

I am not able to understand why is this relation correct, shouldn't it be

$$A_i = A_r + A_t~   ?$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two waves incident and reflected) in the incident region and the displacement of the medium in the incident is the sum of the displacements due to the individual displacements of the two waves.

There is only the transmitted wave in the transmitted region and the displacement of the medium is the displacement of the transmitted wave.

At the interface there can be no discontinuity and so the displacement in the incident region (the sum of two displacements) must equal the displacement in the transmitted region.